# Funky timestamp format

Tags: hadoop, hive

We are getting data from a vendor, and loading it into Hive.  I am unable to cast a date-time field as timestamp (It's all stored as strings). After bashing my head against it for a while, I've finally noticed that there is an hyphen between the day portion of the date and the hour portion of the time:

```
yyyy-mm-dd-hh.mm.ss.SSSSSS
2016-05-18-21.05.21.177152
```

I've been trying to work out a way to handle this with `from_unixtime`, but no luck so far.  I'm pretty sure that's not a valid pattern for a SimpleDateFormat.

Is there any way to handle this that doesn't involve splitting it apart into two strings, and concatenating them back into a valid pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Split the date using substr and replace the '-' in the second part of the string and concat both string.

```
from_unixtime(concat(substr(sdate,0,10)),regexp_replace(substr(sdate,10,16),'-','')))
```